# What's the best way to create landing pages In magento?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, magento-1.7

I was wondering if the best way to create landing pages and templates for these in Magento is to create cms pages ?

Write static blocks and then create a new cms page all the time or is there another good way to do this ? 
Is a category page better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using category pages and there I add static blocks or whatever I need. It is a pretty standard process and gives me lots of freedom to create and design the pages the way I want. Using XML Layout updates I can hide/show blocks and every single piece of the website.

1. Create Subcategory
2. Use static blocks if you have specific content (this allows all HTMT etc.)
3. XML layout update show/hide blocks, breadcrumbs, sidebar etc.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are fine. From an organizational standpoint, I prefer the CMS method.

### CMS METHOD

> 1. Open an FTP Client (e.g. Filezilla) and navigate to your template directory
>      app/design/frontend/default/[YOUR THEME]/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml
>
>    > Note: If you do not see a navigation/ directory in your template directory, you will have to copy the directory from app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/navigation
> 2. In the top.phtml file, add the following line

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
->setBlockId('nav_links')->toHtml() ?>
```

> after this line

```
<?php echo $_menu ?>
```

> 3. Login to your Magento admin panel and navigate to CMS > Static Blocks
> 4. Create a new static block. Below are details:
>
> > Block Title: Navigation Links
> >
> > Identifier: nav_links
> >
> > Status: Enabled
> >
> > Content:

```
<li><a href="{{store url=''}}"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url='about'}}"><span>About</span></a></li>
<li><a href="{{store url='contact'}}"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
```

> 5. Save the new static block
> 6. If you need to add more pages, create the CMS pages and then edit the "nav_links" static block and include the page title and name.
>
> > Note: Make sure that CMS pages have been created first.

Hopefully this helps out.